# pandas filter dataframes based on missing column date

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs,

df1 (with repetition rows):

```
mean_date     d_id         p_val    x_mean
2021-04-02    x_122        7        0.32
2021-04-03    x_122        7        0.54
2021-04-02    x_122        7        0.23
2021-04-03    x_122        7        0.31

..
2021-03-28    x_222        2        1.2
2021-03-29    x_222        2        2.2
```

df2:

```
mean_date     d_id  
2021-03-28    x_122      
2021-03-29    x_122      
2021-03-30    x_122      
2021-03-31    x_122      
.
.
2021-03-30    x_222      
2021-03-31    x_222      
2021-04-01    x_222      
2021-04-02    x_222
```

and the result_df should be:

res_df:

since for `d_id`  `x_122` the `p_val` is `7` and there are only 2 (unique mean_date rows in `df_1`) so we will log the remaining `5`, but not for `d_id = x_222` as it fulfills the `p_val = 2` for its rows.

```
mean_date     d_id  
2021-03-28    x_122      
2021-03-29    x_122      
2021-03-30    x_122      
2021-03-31    x_122
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read the pandas manual? You are asking a pretty basic question.

Comment: I tried to filter out df2 based on the matching d_id value but not sure how to check for unique dates and compare the p_val in df1